# DAX: Getting all rows with a column value that appears X times?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a table where each row is a product sold in a store. A product has two relevant columns, EAN and Store. How do I find all products (that have the same EAN) that appear in all Stores? For example, if Store A has products with EANs 1, 2 and 3, Store B has 2, 3 and 4 and Store C has 2, 3 and 5 (9 rows in total), how can I get all rows where EAN is 2 or 3 (6 rows in total)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a calculated column to your model, then use this as a filter.

```
=calculate(counta(product[EAN]),filter(all(product),product[EAN] = EARLIER(product[EAN])))
```

[Screenshot of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipxkb.png)

You can then use this value to compare with Total number of stores. 
For this you can use the distinctcount measure.